# MotionLayout onSwipe autocomplete speed

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

Is there any way I can speed up the animation that plays when I stop mid-swipe in a `MotionLayout` with an `onSwipe` transition? Currently it transitions very slowly to the start or end position.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was wondering if there's such thing as autoComplete duration too. 
After some research I've found out that using `app:maxAcceleration` parameter on `onSwipe` helps to gain the control over this duration.

e.g.

```
<OnSwipe
        app:maxAcceleration="40"
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:touchAnchorId="@+id/view_one"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top"
        app:touchRegionId="@id/view_one"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You explain more detailed what You want to do?

You can set the duration of Your transistion in Your XML File...if that was a part of Your question.

```
 <Transition
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    app:duration="340">
</Transition>
```

GGK